# Cant format, mount or list external hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive

So I have a 1TB internal Samsung M.2 SSD and a 1TB external SSD and i wanted to install gentoo on it. I installed gentoo and wanted to format the external hard drive but now, on my Mint system, the external hard drive does not show up at all. When I tried listing all connected hard drives with 'fdisk -l' it lists all hard drives and partitions except my external drive. I tried it with gparted but when I have the external drive connected to my PC it does not even start until I unplug the hard drive. I also tried to format the drive with 'mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb' but it does nothing until I manually stop it. I searched for a solution online but nobody seemed to have the same problem. I dont have any clue what could have caused this but I think that I messed something up on the gentoo install. Does anybody have an idea what could have caused this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is confusing and missing information.  If you tail stslog is the hardware recignised when plugged in? Where does /dev/sdb come from? Why are you formatting an entire drive and what dies it say?  Assuming /dev/sdb is the external ssd, why cant you use fdisk /dev/sdb? Have you checked that the ssd works on other systems and that its not a hardware fault?

Comment: It is detecting the hard disk but it is constantly disconnecting. I tried it on windows and same problem there. I tried it with fdisk but when im trying to delete or make a new partition it says 'input-/output error'. I tried other USB ports too but same problem there. I also tried it on my laptop with mint and windows still the same problem :(.